# Visual Studio/C# Entity Data Model

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, ado.net-entity-data-model

I setup a EDM for a SQL database in visual studio. I set the connection string in a configuration file but my question is how I can test if the database was properly connected.

If I put a broken connection string for the database in the config file, the program still boots and makes its way to the queries, then it throws an exception. How can I ensure that the string has made a successful connection or not?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make a call to check if the DataBase exists

```
using (var ctx = new BonsaiEntities())
{
   if ( ctx.DatabaseExists() ) {
   };
}
```

Comment: Thats embarrassing... will read the API more thoroughly next time. Thanks.